# How to get rid of "This app is causing your device to run slowly" notification (app development time)?

Tags: android, galaxy

When an Android app is being developed, debugged, and tested, there is a lot of code exceptions being occurred. Almost each exception causes an Android device (Galaxy Note 3, Android 5.0 - if it matters) pops up the annoying **"This app is causing your device to run slowly"** notification with crash statistics and suggestion to uninstall the app. Is there any way to get rid of this annoying notification?

Selecting the app as a debug app in Developer Options does not help.

Comment: where you able to fix it? what did you do? i am getting the same notification and its irritating

Comment: Nope, I haven't found any solution other than trying to write code that does not produce exceptions :)

Comment: i guess i will go the same way.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons for this to be happening. For instance:

- Too many exceptions being thrown from within a possibly infinite loop
- Race conditions between threads and/or poorly implemented
  [spinlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock)
- [Excessive debug verbose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845073/does-too-many-log-writing-decreases-android-application-performance) (try reducing the amount of messages or 
  tuning the severities)
- Unnecessary screen and/or components re-drawing (see [this article about UI optimization](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html))

Of course these are very generic points that should be analysed carefully.

Comment: Thanks! But the question is not "why?" (I know why, multiple errors/exceptions are always present when you develop a new app), the question is "how to disable the annoying notification?".

Comment: Does Samsung provides any document what is monitored by this app? I have an app which did not have a single crash in a week and works only in backgroud. Yet I still get these notifications about my app.